# Kernel driver for wireless adapter not in use

Tags: kernel, wifi

I recently installed Archlinux on my laptop, and as per the instructions on the Arch Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Check_the_driver_status) I checked the output of the 'lspci -k' command.

The sample output from the wiki is like this:

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

When I run the command, my output is this:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device 2123
```

I noticed that the 'Kernel driver in use' and 'kernel modules' fields are not displayed. Being new to the OS, I have no idea what that means or what to do about it.

How do I get the kernel to 'use' my wireless adapter? If it matters, I'm booting the OS from a USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Broadcom devices have a weird history with respect to Arch Linux.

I found this [Arch Linux wiki article](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194393) which seems to be your question exactly.  The salient advice given is this:

```
Install broadcom-wl from aur, unload the brcmsmac and load the wl module.
```

That AUR package is [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl/). Oddly, the Broadcom page referenced from the AUR page doesn't claim that is supports BCM4352, but quite a few other [Arch forum pages](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=184687) say that the broadcom-wl package both works and doesn't work.

Comment: Would you elaborate on how I install it? I can't download it on Linux without an internet connection and I don't know how to transfer it from my downloads folder in Windows.

Comment: @TheDerkus - I've never set up or used a dual boot machine, and I only use Windows at work. I would guess that you could `mount` the Windows disk when you've booted from a USB drive, but I don't know for sure. That's really another question.